# How to Acces Button In TDBNavigator (exe build with Delphi) using pyWinAuto

Tags: python, delphi, pywinauto

How to Acces Button In TDBNavigator using pyWinAuto ?

when id call method print_control_identifiers i can not find buttons in DBNavigator.
here is my Code :

```
import time

try:
   from pywinauto import application
except ImportError:
   import os.path
   pywinauto_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
   pywinauto_path = os.path.split(os.path.split(pywinauto_path)[0])[0]
   import sys
   sys.path.append(pywinauto_path)
   from pywinauto import application

from pywinauto import tests
from pywinauto.findbestmatch import MatchError
from pywinauto import findwindows
from pywinauto import WindowAmbiguousError
from pywinauto.controls import WrapHandle

from pywinauto.timings import Timings
Timings.Fast()

app = application.Application()
app.connect_(path = "D:\SharedProjects\Projects\pyWinAuto\PYWINAUTO.exe")
pwin = app.MAIN
pwin.MenuSelect("Transaksi->Form 2")


frmDua = app['Form Dua']
frmDua.print_control_identifiers()

dbNavigator = frmDua['TDBNavigator']
dbNavigator.print_control_identifiers()
```

result of dbNavigator.print_control_identifiers() are :

```
Control Identifiers:
TDBNavigator - ''   (L673, T285, R1335, B310)
'3' 'TDBNavigator'
```

there is not button in TDBNavigator. So, how can i access btnFirst, btnPrev, btnInsert, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , Finaly I Found It

```
dbNavigator = frmDua['TDBNavigator']
dbNavigator.SetFocus()
SendKeys.SendKeys("""{LEFT 10}""") #Move Cursor To Most LeftButton
SendKeys.SendKeys("""{RIGHT 4}""") #Move Cursor To InsertButton
SendKeys.SendKeys("""{SPACE}""")   #Perform Click On Insert Button
```